# Making JS discord bot allow for other bots to give it command

Tags: javascript, discord

I am trying to make a music bot that allows for another bot to call commands. For example, a bot could call !play and the music bot would read it and then play the music. I have successfully copied a music bot using the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K2nqthN1xKQ, and his code https://github.com/zhycorp/disc-11. However, it will allow me to make another bot that can call its code, is there any to make the music bot zhycorp allow for other bots to command it. Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Is this Microsoft JS bot framework

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to tell, however I have asked the create about it, and will get back to you when I find the answer